# JMC Historical Data Settings, persisted_jmx_data folder naming

Tags: java, performance, monitoring, jmc

Im using Java Mission Control 5.5 and are currently monitoring a number of remove JVM applications. From time to time the applications are rebooted and I need to restart the JMC, and then of course I loose all historical data.

"Historical Data Settings" seems to be just what I need to solve this but why are Oracle using some kind of hashed value to name the folders of the monitored connections. Is there some configuration to name these or should I just accept that JMC properly doesn't support persistance

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I looked at our code, there is no way to configure the folder names :(, but the id's should be the same between restarts of JMC, and I believe they should be the same if you restart your server application but keep the same : name for it. Is this the behavior you see?